# Use Flask's Click CLI with the app factory pattern

Tags: python, flask, command-line-interface, python-click, flask-script

I define my Flask application using the app factory pattern. When using Flask-Script, I can pass the factory function to the `Manager`. I'd like to use Flask's built-in Click CLI instead. How do I use the factory with Click?

My current code uses Flask-Script. How do I do this with Click?

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_script import Manager, Shell

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    ...
    return app

manager = Manager(create_app)

def make_shell_context():
    return dict(app=app, db=db, User=User, Role=Role)

manager.add_command('shell', Shell(make_context=make_shell_context))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager.run()
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The `flask` command is a Click interface created with `flask.cli.FlaskGroup`. Create your own group and pass it the factory function. Use `app.shell_context_processor` to add objects to the shell.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.cli import FlaskGroup
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy()

def create_app(script_info=None):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    db.init_app(app)
    ...

    @app.shell_context_processor
    def shell_context():
        return {'app': app, 'db': db}

    return app

cli = FlaskGroup(create_app=create_app)

@cli.command
def custom_command():
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cli()
```

Run your file instead of the `flask` command. You'll get the Click interface using your factory.

```
FLASK_DEBUG=1 python app.py run
```

---

Ideally, create an entry point and install your package in your env. Then you can call the script as a command. Create a `setup.py` file with at least the following.

```
project/
    app/
        __init__.py
    setup.py
```

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name='my_app',
    version='1.0.0',
    packages=find_packages(),
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'app=app:cli',
        ],
    },
)
```

```
pip install -e /path/to/project
FLASK_DEBUG=1 app run
```

---

Using your own CLI is less robust than the built-in `flask` command. Because your `cli` object is defined with your other code, a module-level error will cause the reloader to fail because it can no longer import the object. The `flask` command is separate from your project, so it's not affected by errors in your module.

Answer (score 4):

Newly updated for Flask >= 2.1. See my other answer for Flask < 2.1.

In order to pass arguments to our app, we store them in `script_info`. And in order to do that, we create a custom Click interface using `flask.cli.FlaskGroup`.

However, passing `script_info` directly to app factories is [deprecated in Flask 2](https://github.com/pallets/flask/issues/3552), so we use
Click's `get_current_context` function to get the current context and then access `script_info` from that context.

`manage.py`

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import click
import config

from click import get_current_context
from flask import Flask
from flask.cli import FlaskGroup, pass_script_info


def create_app(*args, **kwargs):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    ctx = get_current_context(silent=True)

    if ctx:
        script_info = ctx.obj
        config_mode = script_info.config_mode
    elif kwargs.get("config_mode"):
        # Production server, e.g., gunincorn 
        # We don't have access to the current context, so must
        # read kwargs instead.
        config_mode = kwargs["config_mode"]

    ...    
    return app


@click.group(cls=FlaskGroup, create_app=create_app)
@click.option('-m', '--config-mode', default="Development")
@pass_script_info
def manager(script_info, config_mode):
    script_info.config_mode = config_mode
    ...


if __name__ == "__main__":
    manager()
```

Now you can run the dev server and set your desired `config_mode` by using either `-m` or `--config-mode`. Note, until Flask 2.1 drops you have to install [Flask@aa13521d42bfdb](https://github.com/pallets/flask/pull/4461)

```sh
pip install git+https://github.com/pallets/flask.git@aa13521d42bfdb
python manage.py -m Production run
```

Production servers like gunincorn don't have access to the current context, so we pass what we need via `kwargs`.

```sh
gunicorn app:create_app\(config_mode=\'Production\'\) -w 3 -k gevent
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to pass arguments to your app factory, you need to make use of `script_info` like so...

`manage.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import click
import config

from flask import Flask
from flask.cli import FlaskGroup, pass_script_info


def create_app(script_info):
    app = Flask(__name__)

    if script_info.config_mode:
        obj = getattr(config, script_info.config_mode)
        flask_config.from_object(obj)

    ...    
    return app


@click.group(cls=FlaskGroup, create_app=create_app)
@click.option('-m', '--config-mode', default="Development")
@pass_script_info
def manager(script_info, config_mode):
    script_info.config_mode = config_mode


if __name__ == "__main__":
    manager()
```

`config.py`

```
class Config(object):
    TESTING = False

class Production(Config):
    DATABASE_URI = 'mysql://user@localhost/foo'

class Development(Config):
    DATABASE_URI = 'sqlite:///app.db'

class Testing(Config):
    TESTING = True
    DATABASE_URI = 'sqlite:///:memory:'
```

now in the command line you can do `manage -m Production run` (after either adding the `entry_points` to `setup.py` as @davidism mentioned, or running `pip install manage.py`).

Answer (score 0):

I found another way to add `click.Option`s to all Flask commands and pass the options to `create_app`. It's a similar approach to @reubano's answer.

```py
from flask import Flask
from flask.cli import FlaskGroup, ScriptInfo
import click

def create_app(say_hi: bool = False, say_goodbye: bool = False):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    
    if say_hi:
        print("hi")
    if say_goodbye:
        print("goodbye")

    return app


def update_create_app(ctx: click.Context, param: click.Option, value):
    """updates Flask's ScriptInfo instance for click commands, updating the create_app callable with our extra
    cli options."""
    if value is None:
        return None

    info = ctx.ensure_object(ScriptInfo)
    params = info.data.get("create_app_args", {})
    info.data["create_app_args"] = {**params, param.human_readable_name: value}
    info.create_app = lambda: create_app(**info.data["create_app_args"])
    return value


_hi = click.Option(
    ["--say-hi"],
    is_flag=True,
    default=False,
    callback=update_create_app,
)
_bye = click.Option(
    ["--say-goodbye"],
    is_flag=True,
    default=False,
    callback=update_create_app,
)


@click.group(cls=FlaskGroup, params=(_hi, _bye))
def customized_flask(*args, **kwargs):
    ...
```