# Access\Read Flask Env Variable within app

Tags: flask

I can't seem to access my env variables' values inside my app. I'm loading my env variables into my app with a `.env` file and the `dotenv` package; I learned about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54600434/how-to-set-flask-env-inside-config-file).

My `.env`

```
FLASK_ENV=development
FLASK_APP=app.py
DEBUG=ON
TESTING=False
```

I want to use the value of the `TESTING` variable inside my app and run certain code based on whether it is True or False.

How can I get these values? The docs say

> Certain configuration values are also forwarded to the Flask object so
>   you can read and write them from there: app.testing = True

But I get `module 'app' has no attribute 'testing'`

When I log `app` by itself I see a `Flask` object. When I log this out like `app.Flask`, I see the env variables, but these appear like this, with no refernce to the current value.

```
{'__name__': 'TESTING', 'get_converter': None}
```

I want to be able to do something like:

```
app.testing => False
app.FLASK_ENV => development
```

and then eventually:

```
if app.testing == True:
    <do something>
```

PS - I know the app loads this `.env` file okay because if I remove the values the environment changes back to production, the default.

```
#settings.py
from pathlib import Path  # python3 only
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv(verbose=True)
env_path = Path('.') / '.env'
load_dotenv(dotenv_path=env_path)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import os
print(os.environ['TESTING'])
```

Equivalent in JS is `process.env`